# Calling chosen functions from the list of functions for several objects

Tags: r, function

I've made a function that applies several functions on several objects. I have them in the list because this all should be wrapped in one function

```
myFunc <- function(...) {
  myApply <- function(...){
  flist <- list(min, max, mean, sum)
  lapply(flist, function(f) f(...))
}
# apply function to several objects  
lapply(list(...), myApply)
}

obj1 <- c(1:9)
obj2 <- c(1:7)

myFunc(obj1, obj2)
```

My question is how to call not all functions from the list, but for example, only two of them:
`myFunc(obj1, obj2, list(min, max))`. Also maybe someone knows how to make this construction more neat?

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate the object calls from the function calls by passing the function calls inside list? i.e. suppose you are passing a single function `min`, would that still be inside list `myFun(obj1, obj2, list(min))`

Comment: i need function call to look like this `myFun(obj1, obj2, list(min))`, yes. Probably I don't need the function list inside. Differentiating it isn't necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this approach?

```
myFun <- function(...,fns) lapply(fns,\(i) lapply(list(...),i))
```

Usage:

```
myFun(obj1,obj2, fns=list(min, max))
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you! But how to take this `list` away from the call? I'm trying to put an ellipsis in objects `lapply` and in function arguments, but getting an error

Comment: see my edit.. Do you mean take the list of objects away?  That is the functions are still passed as a list, but  now the function signature is `function(...,fns)`

Comment: Note that you can not call it like this: `myFun(obj1, obj2, list(min,max))`, because then the list of functions (in this case min and max) are part of the dot-dot-dot. Instead call the functions with a named argument like in my solution.

Comment: Yes, like this! mine didn't work because i didn't use named argument. Could you please clarify what does `\(i)` mean?

Comment: `\(i)` is a short cut for `function(i)`.. It is available in R versions >=4.1